# R: Análise espacial com spatstat, barra lateral não não mostra valores corretos

Tags: r

estou tentando criar um mapa com o pacote `spatstat` do `R` de forma que a barra lateral mostre os valores da terceira (de preferência) ou quarta coluna do meu data frame e que as cores tmb sejam reflexo dessa terceira (ou quarta coluna) escolhida.

Meu script:

```
#dados

x=c(6.839887, 6.671494, 6.651083, 6.655289, 6.591903, 6.653641, 6.661709, 6.671664, 6.660044, 6.624659, 6.648162, 6.536877, 6.654134, 6.674678,6.618935, 6.677705, 6.643918, 6.644119, 6.670517, 6.583619, 6.649991, 6.647649, 6.656308, 6.645772, 6.648740, 6.643103, 6.652199, 6.666641,6.633400, 6.621282, 6.635427, 6.646127, 6.630862, 6.657919, 6.671616, 6.622935, 6.648225, 6.676911, 6.640234, 6.719334, 6.653202, 6.656747,6.724692, 6.639747, 6.630575, 6.657916, 6.618957, 6.640006, 6.645280, 6.614058, 6.576136, 6.631994, 6.617391, 6.782351, 6.620072, 6.661061,6.597216, 6.648755, 6.618436, 6.659507, 6.653993, 6.663255, 6.630893, 6.656322, 6.617265, 6.649022, 6.629346, 6.595224, 6.540263, 6.623435,6.652709, 6.608565, 6.618335, 6.645100, 6.790914, 6.643620, 6.462808, 6.680115, 6.716004, 6.668781, 6.765199, 6.674251, 6.647542, 6.724564,6.724556)
 
y=c(17.16749, 17.16727, 17.16678, 17.16673, 17.16813, 17.16663, 17.16652, 17.16636, 17.16629, 17.16856, 17.16521, 17.16519, 17.17002, 17.16465,17.17015, 17.16407, 17.16356, 17.17122, 17.16334, 17.17152, 17.16282, 17.16278, 17.16272, 17.17257, 17.16198, 17.17279, 17.16169, 17.16161,17.16146, 17.17352, 17.17389, 17.16076, 17.17420, 17.16046, 17.15917, 17.17571, 17.15895, 17.15881, 17.15860, 17.15827, 17.15797, 17.15776,17.17761, 17.15664, 17.15622, 17.15610, 17.15571, 17.15561, 17.15527,17.15514, 17.15494, 17.15447, 17.15438, 17.18041, 17.18053, 17.15402,17.18090, 17.15384, 17.18121, 17.15355, 17.15352, 17.15349, 17.18213,17.15242, 17.15201, 17.14978, 17.18591, 17.18688, 17.18707, 17.18761,17.14712, 17.18788, 17.18794, 17.14619, 17.18868, 17.14588, 17.14511,17.14471, 17.14440, 17.14430, 17.19116, 17.19140, 17.14222, 17.14123,17.33627)

z=c(32.23228,526.46061, -1300.03539, -376.04329, 139.67322,-913.24800,  -526.46061, 354.55511, 483.48424, 161.16141, 182.64960, 419.0196, 75.20866, -225.62598, -1536.40546, -397.53148, -1106.64169,  -440.50786, 118.18504,-290.09054, -1471.94089, 440.50786,-848.78343, -1385.98814, -676.87793, -1622.35821, -1450.45271,75.20866, -1557.89365, 161.16141, 376.04329, 354.55511, -32.23228,-1171.10626,-75.20866, 547.94880, -805.80706, 870.27162, -698.36612,-32.23228, -2331.46842,  -182.64960, 75.20866, -719.85431,-1837.24009,913.24800, -1106.64169, 698.36612, 483.48424, -676.87793, -3019.09045, 891.75981, 1106.64169, 333.06692, -913.24800,333.06692, 934.73619, 354.55511, 75.20866, -891.75981, -247.11416, -1966.16922, 139.67322, -784.31887, -569.43699, -118.18504,-440.50786, 397.53148, -655.38974, 139.67322, 53.72047, -633.90155,-633.90155, 419.01967, -547.94880, 75.20866, 569.43699, 290.09054, -376.04329, 547.94880, 75.20866, -10.74409, 182.64960,-397.53148, -479.53833 )

w=c(96326.91, 96769.46, 95127.94, 95960.41, 96423.22, 95476.93, 95825.18,96615.67, 96731.03, 96442.47, 96461.73, 96673.36, 96365.44, 96095.53,94914.31, 95941.10, 95302.53, 95902.47, 96403.96, 96037.64, 94972.60,96692.58, 95535.03, 95050.29, 95689.84, 94836.56, 94992.03, 96365.44,94894.87, 96442.47, 96634.90, 96615.67, 96269.09, 95244.36, 96230.54,96788.68, 95573.74, 97076.62, 95670.50, 96269.09, 94193.69, 96134.12,96365.44, 95651.15, 94642.01, 97114.98, 95302.53, 96923.12, 96731.03,95689.84, 93567.91, 97095.80, 97287.46, 96596.43, 95476.93, 96596.43,97134.15, 96615.67, 96365.44, 95496.30, 96076.24, 94525.17, 96423.22,95593.10, 95786.52, 96191.98, 95902.47, 96654.13, 95709.18, 96423.22,96346.17, 95728.52, 95728.52, 96673.36, 95805.85, 96365.44, 96807.89,96557.96, 95960.41, 96788.68, 96365.44, 96288.37, 96461.73,95941.10, 99451.20)

shap.lo=data.frame(x,y,z,w)

library(spatstat)
shap.lo.win <- owin(range(shap.lo[,1]), range(shap.lo[,2]))
centroid.owin(shap.lo.win) ; area.owin(shap.lo.win)

shap.lo.ppp <- as.ppp(shap.lo[,c(1,2,3)], shap.lo.win) # fazendo um objeto ppp

plot(density(shap.lo.ppp,0.02), col=topo.colors(25), main='', xlab='x', 
     ylab='y')

points(x, y)
```

O resultado é a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber dos amigos pq a barra lateral mostra valores diferentes daqueles mostrados na terceira coluna do meu data frame, ou seja, além de não exibir nenhum valor negativo mostra valores muito maiores do que aqueles contidos na terceira coluna.

É possível fazer isso, isto é, fazer com que as cores e a barra lateral representem a terceira ou a quarta coluna do data frame ?

Agradeço a ajuda de todos!

Comment: Com esse código, a quarta coluna deve ser difícil, `as.ppp(shap.lo[,c(1,2,3)], etc)` só usa as três primeiras colunas. (E já agora, `shap.lo[, 1:3]` é a mesma coisa e é mais simples e legível.)

Comment: também n vai amigo... perceba que no exemplo utilizo a terceira coluna e os valores são muito acima

Comment: Se calhar não. O que está a utilizar é a densidade, não os dados. Experimente `dns <- density(shap.lo.ppp,0.02); str(dns)` para ver o que está no gráfico.

Comment: Os valores que tem estão no intervalo `range(dns$v)`.

Comment: ahh, entendi. então não existem maneira de fazer com que essas cores e barra lateral mostre os valores da terceira ou quarta coluna ?

Comment: Não, creio que não. Nunca usei esse pacote mas se quer a densidade então os valores serão sempre diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Má Notícia

A barra lateral está mostrando os dados corretos. A função

```
plot(density(shap.lo.ppp,0.02), col=topo.colors(25), main='', xlab='x', 
  ylab='y')
```

está plotando a *densidade gaussiana estimada* para `shap.lo.ppp`. Por definição, uma função densidade não possui valores negativos. Além disso, a integral dela sobre o domínio considerado deve ser igual a 1. Por isso, para que o volume desta superfície que aparece no gráfico seja iguala 1, é necessário que alguns pontos sejam picos bem altos, maiores do que 20000.

Esta é a razão para a tua escala começar em zero e terminar em um valor bem acima do esperado por ti.

### Boa Notícia

Felizmente, é possível enganar o `R` para ele plotar exatamente o que tu deseja. Em primeiro lugar, vou estimar a densidade destes pontos do teu problema:

```
densidade <- density(shap.lo.ppp, 0.02)
```

Com isto feito, vou calcular o mínimo e o máximo de `v`, o objeto que possui os valores da densidade estimada:

```
min(densidade$v)
[1] 1.826526e-12
max(densidade$v)
[1] 23782.84
```

Ou seja, são zero e mais de 20000, como suspeitávamos. Os valores mínimos e máximos da escala que te interessam são dados por

```
min(shap.lo.ppp$marks)
[1] -3019.09
max(shap.lo.ppp$marks)
[1] 1106.642
```

Se definirmos que o mínimo (0) da densidade vale -3019.09 e seu máximo (23782.84) vale 1106.642, basta fazer uma interpolação linear nos valores intermediários de `densidade$v` para transformar a escala naquela que queremos. Escrevi uma função para fazer isto automaticamente:

```
conversao_densidade <- function(densidade, shap.lo){
  # razao entre as amplitudes
  razao     <- (max(densidade$v)-min(densidade$v))/(max(shap.lo$z)-min(shap.lo$z))

  # deslocamento para o valor minimo
  conversao <- densidade$v/razao+min(shap.lo$z)

  # resultado
  return(conversao)
}
```

Agora é só substituir `densidade$v` pelos valores interpolados e fazer um novo gráfico, desta vez com a escala desejada:

```
densidade$v <- conversao_densidade(densidade, shap.lo)

plot(densidade, col=topo.colors(25), main='', xlab='x', 
 ylab='y')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado Marcos, realmente a barra lateral agora mostra os valores da coluna que eu pretendia, muito agradecido. Porém ainda há um desacordo entre os valores de `shap.lo$z` e as cores correspondentes. Por exemplo, o ponto
 `x =6.6334 ; y=17.16146  ; z = -1557.894 ; w=94894.87`
localiza-se no gráfico entre as cores amarelas e a bege, isto é, cores que indicam valores mais positivos ( [figura](https://ibb.co/khgD9H) ), sendo que o valor de `z = -1557.894`. Alguma sugestão de como solucionar ?

Comment: Isto não pode ser feito através da densidade. Como escrevi acima, a função `density ` vai te dar a _densidade gaussiana estimada_ para `shap.lo.ppp`. Portanto, a altura de alguns pontos vai ser aproximada por esta estimativa. Não é um problema que precisa ser solucionado.